# Open Image, thats inside of a .jar file

Tags: java, jar

i know that this question was asked several times before but none of the solutions quite work for my problem (or i just dont know how to adjust them properly).

I try to program an application, that is supposed to open an image, which is located inside of the jar file of the application.

The jar file is created by maven, so originally the picture was in the src/main/resources directory of my maven project and it will finally be in the base directory of my jar file.

The program itself consist of two java files and an fxml file. The one java file is my main class (called imageviewer.java) and the other java file is my javafx controller (called Contoller.java).

The method, that is supposed to open the picture is in the Controller.java file.

The solutions I found were all using getclass().getResources... , but in this case it does not work (maybe because it is not a jar file that will consist of a single class). The name of the final maven-generated jar file will be imageviewer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar.

How can I access the image inside it?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I did actually find the solution.

In Eclipse I was only able to acess the image while it was in the same folder as the java documents. After I moved it into the "Resources" folder (which is where it belongs in a maven project) i was not able to acess it with a relative path.

All I had to do was creating a new package inside of the resources folder that is called exactly the same as the package in which the java files are.

So my project structure now looks like this:

src/main/java/myPackageName/MyJavaFiles.java

and

src/main/resources/myPackageName/Imagename.jpg

After that i was able to acess is with getClass().getResourcesAsStream("Imagename.jpg");